# force redirect with https and with www

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect my website with https and www. I want to remove the tailing shash from the url and force to redirect with https and need to redirect with `www.test.com` if given `test.com` .

```
http://www.test.com  -> https://www.test.com
http://test.com      -> https://www.test.com
http://test.com/     -> https://www.test.com
```

I have tried as

```
#Trailing Slash Removal 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|offs()
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.test.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

now getting redirect with http://test.com to https://www.test.com  properly but https://test.com will through error as `This site can’t provide a secure connection` how to get it redirect

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways like below.

Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS

**1. Redirect All Web Traffic**
If you have existing code in your .htaccess, add the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

**2. Redirect Only a Specific Domain
For redirecting a specific domain to use HTTPS, add the following:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

**3. Redirect Only a Specific Folder
Redirecting to HTTPS on a specific folder, add the following:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/folder/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do both `http -> https` and `non-www to www` in a single rule without hardcoding your domain name.

Use this rule in your site root ,htaccess or in Apache config:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure this is your **top most rule** and remove all other rules handling `http->https` and `www`.

Comment: can you please alter my full ifmodule

Comment: I have provided you full code. Just replace all the code you have shown in question with this and test in a new browser.

Comment: Please test. Trailing slash in `http://test.com/ ` will be auto removed by browser itself.

Comment: What URL is not redirecting as you expect and what error are you getting?

Comment: https://test.com/ caught This site can’t provide a secure connection error

Comment: `This site can’t provide a secure connection error ` is because you don't have SSL cert configured. Just rename this .htaccess and retest with `https://test.com/` to see the behavior.

Comment: will check it and get u back in an hour

Comment: `still getting 500`: You never reported 500 earlier :) Anyway for any 500 error you must check your Apache error.log file. It is usually caused by some mis configuration or typo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206692/discussion-between-anubhava-and-user3386779).