# How to redirect my website with the URL with www?

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, server

Currently misitoweb.es works with https://misitoweb.es

It also works when I put misitoweb.es in the browser bar

However, when I use [www.misitoweb.es](http://www.misitoweb.es) it does not work. The browser says the following:

***This page does not work.
The page [www.misitioweb.es](http://www.misitioweb.es) has redirected you too many times.***

How can I make the www format. Also direct me to my website?

What should I do so that all formats redirect me to https://mysiteweb.es?

The URL I have in WordPress is https://mysiteweb.es I have tried adding a code fragment to the project's .htaccess file, but it doesn't work:

```
# Redirect to the version without "www"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.es [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysiteweb.es/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I have also tried some of the proposals offered on Stackoverflow, like the following, but for some reason Redirect web domain in with wordpress does not work

[force redirect with https and with www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891920/force-redirect-with-https-and-with-www)

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/197912/redireccionar-dominio-web-en-con-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of redirection you want, you will need to exclude either the `WWW` or the `non-WWW` version to avoid ending up in a loop.

Here is an example that forces SSL and non-WWW. It also meets the conditions for HSTS preload.
The code **must be inserted before** the WordPress directives.

It's good practice to use `R=302` for testing to avoid potential caching issues. So, after testing and if everything works as expected, change `R=302` to `R=301`.

If you want to use it within a subfolder, e.g. `myfolder`, change:
`RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /myfolder/`

If you still get a loop error, check for other redirecting directives in your `.htaccess` file.

```
# FORCE SSL AND NON-WWW

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=302,L]
```

**EDIT: I've updated my answer regarding the OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77152111/how-to-redirect-my-website-with-the-url-with-www/77153808#comment136017961_77153808).**

Basically, you have the option to choose between 2 variants of how your website should be addressed. The WWW variant or the non-WWW variant. However, you have to choose one as your canonical domain and stick with it. In the htaccess file, redirect the unselected variant to the selected one. That's also what my code above does, where `https://mywebsite.es` is your canonical URL:

`http://mywebsite.es` is redirected to `https://mywebsite.es`
`http://www.mywebsite.es` is redirected to `https://mywebsite.es`
`https://www.mywebsite.es` is redirected to `https://mywebsite.es`
`http://www.mywebsite.es/something/` is redirected to `https://mywebsite.es/something/`
*and so on ...*

The opposite would be, as already mentioned, to choose the WWW version using `https://www.mywebsite.es` as canonical URL. To do this you would have to use the following (again, after testing change `R=302` to `R=301`):

```
# FORCE SSL AND WWW

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# FORCE SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
# FORCE WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

`http://mywebsite.es` is redirected to `https://www.mywebsite.es`
`http://www.mywebsite.es` is redirected to `https://www.mywebsite.es`
`https://mywebsite.es` is redirected to `https://www.mywebsite.es`
*and so on ...*

You can read more about choosing between www and non-www URLs here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Choosing_between_www_and_non-www_URLs

**Another question the OP asked was:**

> I really don't know what the WordPress directives code snippet is

**Answer:**

Open your `.htaccess` file and search for the following line, this is where the WordPress rules start:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
```

Whereas the following line indicates the end of the WP directives:

```
# END WordPress
```

So everything between these two lines is WordPress related. The default code added by WordPress should look something like this (it looks a little different for multisite or non-english installations).

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

**As mentioned, my rules from above must be inserted before these specific WordPress rules.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need that all types of `URLs` can be used and that they always redirect to SSL: with `www`, without `www`, with `https`, mywebsite.es, etc. I really don't know what the WordPress directives code snippet is, I don't know if it would be an error to show my `.htaccess` file, what do you think about it? Would it be a security problem for my website to show that file here?

Comment: Sorry for the bad or misleading explanation. I've updated my answer with some more details.